# Parse javascript login across subdomains

Tags: parse-platform, local-storage

Using the `Parse.User.login()` method, can I somehow make a login on `bar.foo.com` then make the user logged in on `baz.foo.com`?

I would normally just set the cookie domain to be `foo.com`, but it seems it is using localStorage for the login. I would rather not do anything over-comlicated with postMessage across iframes if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt):

To have your cookie available to all sub-domains, use "." before the domain name.

```
document.cookie = encodeURI(cookieName) + "=" + 
cookieValue + ";domain=.example.com;path=/;expires=" + myDate;
```

Comment: Parse uses localStorage, not cookies for its user accounts

Comment: @PaulTarjan Yes, I understand that. You said you usually use cookie domain to be foo.com so i showed you how to set the cookie to all subdomains as well. If that is not the answer you were looking for, my apologies.